# I cant make the program continue to loop if its invalid input is entered

Tags: python-3.x

I have this program:

```
number =  int(input('Contact Number:'))
def validatePhoneNumber(number):
    count = 0
    while True:
        while number > 0:
            number = number//10
            count = count+1
        if (count == 10) :
            break

        elif (count > 10) :
            print('Invalid phone number')
            return -1

        elif (count < 10):
            print('Invalid phone number')
            return -1

validatePhoneNumber(number)
```

it will appear like this:

```
Contact Number:1234
Invalid phone number
>>>
```

I want it to continue to loop until a 10 digit number is entered then it will stop.

```
Contact Number:1234567890
>>>
```

The condition is that If the number is missing or invalid, return ‐1.
Am I missing something inside the program?
Thanks

Comment: This is a terrible usage of an infinite loop. What about checking the length only when a character was entered?

Comment: Why are you treating it as an `int` and not a string? If `0000000001` was a valid phone number, you're getting rid of 9 digits... Why not just something like: `if number.isdigit() and len(number) == 10: break` otherwise, keep asking

Comment: I think what you want to do is to put the last and the first row in a do while loop so if the input is wrong you will call the function again

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
number = input('Contact Number:')  # it's a str now, so we can use len(number)
def validatePhoneNumber(number):
    while len(number) != 10:
        number = input("Please enter a 10-digit contact number: ")
    return number

number = validatePhoneNumber(number)
```

It's a more pythonic approach and therefore easier to understand and debug. Also as other comments pointed out, leading 0s aren't stripped away now.